# I am getting an error "IdentifierExpected " in specflow feature file

Tags: c#, specflow

Scenario Outline: Create a new employee with mandatory details with different iteration.

**When I fill all the mandatory details in the form `<Name>`, `<Age>`**

And press the submit button then All the details should be saved in application and db

```
Examples:

   | Name     |  | Age |
   | Malavika |  | 29  |
   | Pranitha |  | 28  |  


[When(@"I fill all the mandatory details in the form '(.*)', '(.*)'")]
public void WhenIFillAllTheMandatoryDetailsInTheForm(string name, int age)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name" + name);
    Console.WriteLine("Age" + age);
}
```

Comment: Is this the code raising the error? which line?

Comment: I am not getting error in the c# code but i am getting error in corresponding specflow feature

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty column. Change

```
| Name     |  | Age |
| Malavika |  | 29  |
| Pranitha |  | 28  |
```

To

```
| Name     | Age |
| Malavika | 29  |
| Pranitha | 28  |
```

Comment: Thank you.Its working now.But previously when i have done the same thing it was working. this was working.                                                                                                
               When I fill all the mandatory details in the form
        | Name     |  | Age |  | Phone      |  | E-Mail                   |
        | Malavika |  | 29  |  | 9650833899 |  | malavika.btech@gmail.com |
        | Pranitha |  | 28  |  | 8712117350 |  | pranitha.btech@gmail.com |

Comment: @MalavikaNarayanaRaoMamidi I don't really know specflow very well, but I'm guessing `||` is acceptable and `| |` (with space) isn't.